# Learning Python, Freq of words

Tags: python

Write a program that reads a list of words. Then, the program outputs those words and their frequencies.

this is my current code. I think I need to add the phase to a dict but, I'm not 100 percent sure that's correct. Any kind of advise or help would be greatly appreciated

```
phase = input()
each_word = phase.split()

for x in each_word:
    word_count = each_word.count(x)

print(*each_word, word_count)
```

Input: `hey hi Mark hi mark`

my output: `hey hi Mark hi mark 1`

Expected output:

```
hey 1
hi 2
Mark 1
hi 2
mark 1
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious that each time through the loop you replace the value of `word_count`, so it will only have the last value when you print the result?

Answer (score 1):

You could `print` inside the loop

```
s = 'hey hi Mark hi mark'

for word in s.split():
   print(f"{word} {s.count(word)}")
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using the python `set` object in order to remove duplicate words. Firstly, you can convert your input to a set and back to a tuple using the following code:

```
phrase = input()
words = phrase.split()
wordlist = tuple(set(words))
```

`wordlist` now does not contain duplicates.

Next, you can use a for loop and print the word counts one by one:

```
for word in wordlist:
    print(f"{word} {words.count(word)}")
```

This should give an output similar to what you're looking for:

```
hey 1
hi 2
Mark 1
mark 1
```

(note that converting a list to a set shuffles the data, and might print the words in the wrong order)

If you would like to print the frequency of a word everytime it occurs, then you can simple remove the line of code that creates the duplicate-less version of the phrase:

```
wordlist = tuple(set(words))
```

and replace `wordlist` in the for loop with `words`, as `wordlist` no longer exists.